# The solution for the picker issue appears loading, how to fix it?

Tags: android, react-native, picker

[image]

That's my code which was fixed in the previous question, and still the error occurs, the data is not showing just showing loading, how to fix that ?

```
const Sub_Map = () => { 
    const [hasLoaded, setHasLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [data, setdata] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    const callApi = async () => {
      await getData();
      setHasLoaded(true);
    };
    callApi();
  }, []);

  const getData = () => {
    fetch('http:// . . . ./aplikasi/restapi.php?op=getJenis')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        // console.log(json);
        setdata(json);
        // console.log(data);
      });
  };
```

Maybe there is another correction for the return part?

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Pilih Data</Text>
      <View style={styles.picker}>
        {hasLoaded ? (
          <ActivityIndicator />
        ) : (
          <Picker
            selectedValue={data}
            onValueChange={itemValue => setdata(itemValue)}>
            {data &&
              data?.map((item, key) => {
                <Picker.Item
                  label={'${item.bencana}'}
                  value={'${item.ID }'}
                  key={key}
                />;
              })}
          </Picker>
        )}
      </View>
     );
    };
```

and this is for API , there may be a correction

```
    function getJenis()
{
    global $conn;
    global $json;
    global $obj;

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bencana_detail ORDER BY bencana ASC");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $hasil[] = array(
            'ID' => $row['id_bencana_detail'],
            'bencana' => $row['bencana']
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($hasil);
}
```

Comment: Your ActivityIndicator seems like not showing until the data is fetched, is this correct?

Comment: yes that's right, the data doesn't appear, but when console.log data appears

Comment: I mean the `ActivityIndicator` should appear before the data is fetched, once the data is loaded, the `AcitivityIndicator` should be removed and shows the picker. However, your code above shows the empty picker in initial render, and once the data is loaded, the empty picker will hide and shows the `AcitivityIndicator` forever. Is that what you want?

Comment: actually not, just display the data in the picker

Comment: Please include image here not as a link to Google drive

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```js
{data.length <= 0 ? (
  <ActivityIndicator />
) : (
  <Picker
    selectedValue={data}
    onValueChange={itemValue => setdata(itemValue)}>
    {data &&
      data?.map((item, key) => {
        <Picker.Item
          label={'${item.bencana}'}
          value={'${item.ID }'}
          key={key}
        />;
      })}
  </Picker>
)}
```